# Linker Error 1201 "error writing to program database" when building Tensorflow with debug symbols

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake

I am on the r1.3 version of the tensorflow sourcecode and trying to build on windows with GPU support and debug symbols `RelWithDebInfo`

My only modifications to the source code are the ones in this commit: https://github.com/stefanseibert/tensorflow/commit/f73d98ce2662438f6f4fa1bfe37d085feb9f77ba and refer to commenting out some code lines to allow AVX support as found in other questions.

I build successfully in Release the DLL version of tensorflow but am trying to use the C++ API extensively and want to step into the tensorflow codebase for debugging. Trying to build with RelWithDebInfo always fails with the following error:

`fatal error LNK1201: error writing to program database 'C:\code\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\RelWithDebInfo\tensorflow.pdb'; 
check for insufficient disk space, invalid path, or insufficient privilege`

I am using the 64bit toolset of Visual Studio 2015, Update 3 and the disk in question has 170 GB of free space. The machine is a 2.3Ghz Xeon CPU with 64GB of main memory. Any ideas of how to successfully building with GPU support on windows / cmake and debug symbols?

Comment: Is it possible the application is already running while you are linking? Then it would not be able to write to the pdb.

Comment: Good point but unfortunately no. Since the build takes quite some time I start it as the only process running and leave the machine working on that.

Comment: Try using procexp (from SysInternals), to find the handle that is holding onto that file. Might give a clue about what's going wrong.